# Unnecessary(?) additional label requests for nodes

Tags: rest, neo4j, label, spring-data-neo4j

First things first my setup is:

```
spring-data-neo4j version: 3.0.0.RELEASE
spring-data-neo4j-rest version: 3.0.0.RELEASE
```

I am using spring neo4j config with remote REST DB access:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement 
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "my.package.repository")
public class Neo4JConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

@Bean
public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    return new SpringRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
}

}
```

I have my repository setup as:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends GraphRepository<GraphProduct>{}
```

While executing findAll() method on that repository:

```
Page<GraphProduct> products = productRepository.findAll(
            new PageRequest(page, size, sort != null ? new Sort(sort) : null));
```

logs show (as expected) cypher query to fetch those objects:

```
Executing remote cypher query: MATCH (`graphProduct`:`GraphProduct`) RETURN `graphProduct` params {}
```

**The problem**

what is unexpected though is that after that, subsequent requests are sent for each node that was fetched:

```
Executing remote cypher query: match (n) where id(n)={nodeId} return labels(n) as labels params {nodeId=32}
Executing remote cypher query: match (n) where id(n)={nodeId} return labels(n) as labels params {nodeId=33}
...
```

as you can imagine this heavily damages performence of the system (30 objects = 30 additional REST requests)

Can I do something that would help with avoiding those additional requests?
Can this data at a very least be returned in a batch query for all nodes at once?

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately it seams that the problem will stay for some time.
I went with @Gwendal google group discussion link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/GZ8XZ-TEc5c%5B1-25-false%5D and it looks like there is no workaround for now.

Only solution I can think of is going back to class name in node property

from the GG discussion:

```
unfortunately labels are not returned from any of the endpoints with the nodes automatically, so they have to be fetched separately.

Sorry for that.

You can return to the Indexed type-representation strategy with using this config:

<bean id="typeRepresentationStrategyFactory" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="graphDatabase"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="Indexed"/>
</bean>

<neo4j:config storeDirectory="graph.db" base-package="com.example.domain,com.example.domain2"/>
<neo4j:repositories base-package="com.example.repositories"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I post a message on google group about these requests: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/GZ8XZ-TEc5c%5B1-25-false%5D

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your link in the answer.  If the contents of the link were to change, your answer would become useless.